# NullPointerException in processing.core.PApplet when using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, processing

I am trying to get Processing to work in IntelliJ IDEA instead of PDE, and I'm encountering a NullPointerException when using multiple classes.

`App.java` - My main class containing the main method.
`Cone.java` - Class that draws a Cone in 3D.

I then have a class `Cone.java`, which is supposed to render a cone. In my `App.java` class., I then create a Cone object, which spits out this NullPointerException when calling the draw function, specifically when trying to set the stroke color with `stroke(0)`:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "processing.core.PGraphics.stroke(int)" because "this.g" is null`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome @averagedodo. Unfortunately this question got closed promptly. In the future it will help to provide more context (e.g. a snippet of your App class, in particular the part where you call `stroke(0);`. It's unclear if Cone or App extend `PApplet`. After calling `size()` in `setup()` (PApplet overriden method) `g` (PGraphics instance) should be set.  Check out [Kevin Workman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77604698/nullpointerexception-in-processing-core-papplet-when-using-intellij-idea). Hopefully it's still up to date. Good luck!

Comment: can you please update your question to include the class with the entry point (`main()`) as well as the class that extends `PApplet` so it's easier to follow ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that if you intend to run a Processing app using IntelliJ you should override two methods:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Main extends PApplet
{
   public static void main(String... args)
   {
     Main m = new Main();
     new PApplet().main(m.getClass().getCanonicalName());
   }

   @Override
   public void settings()
   {
     size(800, 600);
   }

   @Override
   public void setup()
   {
   }
}
```

The only place where you can set the canvas size is in `settings`. The `setup` methods works as in the Processing IDE.

After that you can leverage the power of IntelliJ